# counter_cache increments twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter-cache

Rails 3.2.14

Ruby 2.1.7

When using `counter_cache`, the count column gets incremented by 2 instead of 1. For example:

```
class Finger < BaseModel
  belongs_to :hand, :counter_cache => true
end

class Hand < BaseModel
  has_many :fingers
end
```

So if I do:

```
finger = Finger.new(:hand_id => 1)
finger.save
```

I can see in my console:

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (4.3ms)  INSERT INTO "fingers" ("hand_id") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["hand_id", 311222]
Hand Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "hands".* FROM "hands" WHERE "hands"."id" = 311222 LIMIT 1
SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "hands" SET "fingers_count" = COALESCE("fingers_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "hands"."id" = 311222
(8.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

So as you can see, `COALESCE` only gets called once.

But then:

```
Hand[1].fingers_count
> 2
```

But:

```
Hand[1].fingers.count
> 1
```

In my application, this is all done with out-of-the-box rails forms that create the new Finger related to the Hand.

Comment: isn't by any chance your definition for `fingers_count` defaulted to 1 ?, look at your schema.rb file and see how it is defined.

Comment: No it increments by 2 on every insert. It goes 2, 4, 6, 8, etc.